# How to subscribe for SessionStateItemExpireCallback in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session-state

I searched a lot about this but couldn't find any particular example of real usage. MSDN says a lot about implementing custom session state provider but I don't wanna do that. Could anyone advise how can I perform some actions when session expires

Usecase: 
Session timeout 10 minutes. 
User opens a page and session is created application marks user in database as logged in. One minute after page open user closes browser so in 9 minutes session will expire and app should execute some code to mark user as offline.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try subscribing for the `Session_End` event in Global.asax:

```
protected void Session_End()
{
    ...
    // Remark: don't use Context here, it will be null as the
    // user might have closed his browser long ago => no request/response
    // You could get the corresponding Session.SessionID though
}
```

You should note that this event is only triggered if you are using a `InProc` session. With `SqlServer` and `StateServer` modes this event is never called simply because in the implementation of their corresponding session state providers the SetItemExpireCallback method simply return `false`. [Quoting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479034.aspx):

> How do the built-in session state
>   providers handle expiration callbacks?
>   The in-process session state provider,
>   InProcSessionStateStore, stores
>   session content in the ASP.NET
>   application cache and takes advantage
>   of the cache's sliding-expiration
>   feature to expire sessions when they
>   go for a specified period of time
>   without being accessed. When the
>   provider is notified via a cache
>   removal callback that a session
>   expired from the cache, it notifies
>   SessionStateModule, and
>   SessionStateModule fires a Session_End
>   event. The other two built-in
>   providers—OutOfProcSessionStateStore
>   and SqlSessionStateStore—don't support
>   expiration callbacks. Both return
>   false from SetItemExpireCallback.
>   OutOfProcSessionStateStore uses the
>   application cache to store sessions,
>   but since session data is stored in a
>   remote process (the "state server"
>   process), the provider doesn't attempt
>   to notify SessionStateModule when a
>   session expires. SqlSessionStateStore
>   relies on a SQL Server agent to
>   "scavenge" the session state database
>   and clean up expired sessions. Having
>   the agent notify the provider about
>   expired sessions so the provider
>   could, in turn, notify
>   SessionStateModule would be a tricky
>   endeavor indeed-especially in a Web
>   farm.

Comment: In case if I come to implementing my own session state provider how do I assign it to my application so default one is not used?

Comment: @Dmitriy Elkin, this is done by specifying `mode="Custom"` in web.config and the type of the custom provider. An example is given at the end of the following article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479034.aspx